# Definite Integration having d/dx operator inside the integral sign .

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{d}{dx}\ \frac{1}{1 + 2^{1/x}}\ dx$$

How to approach this integral ?

Should I differentiate the expression and then integrate ?

I tried that but couldn't proceed

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the fundament calculus is not applicable here, derive the expression inside the integral first, which is trivial and gives you:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1 + 2^{1/x}} = \frac{2^{1/x} \ln (2)}{\left(2^{1/x}+1\right)^2 x^2}$$

Then integrate this from $-1$ to $1$, which is another simple integration which gives you

$$\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Do you have to worry about the $2^{1/0}$ in the denominator?

Comment: Wow , that's an incredibly short method . Thank you .

Comment: One should be more careful here... The integral will, in fact, be positive $2/3$ and not $-1/3$ as this calculation gives.

Comment: Around $x=0$, the integrand is behaving so singularly that the Fundamental Theorem is not applicable.

Comment: If you do like this, you should divide into $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ separately.

Comment: @VonNeumann: Certainly the Fundamental Theorem is not applicable here, but it doesn't mean you must to derive the function to integrate it again. It's stupid. So you can apply the theorem by parts: $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(x) dx = f(x)\bigg|_{-1}^{0^-} + f(x)\bigg|_{0^+}^1, $$ where $f(x)$ is $$\frac{1}{2^{1/x}+1} .$$

Comment: @Dog_69 It's not stupid, it's a GREAT exercise.

Answer (score 1):

By using the integration by parts we can solve it in a very easy way as Dog_69 pointed out.

$$\int_1^{+1} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1 + 2^{1/x}}\ dx = \frac{1}{1 + 2^{1/x}}\bigg|_{-1}^0 + \frac{1}{1 + 2^{1/x}}\bigg|_0^{1}$$

The result is simply

$$\frac{1}{1 + 2} = \frac{2}{3}$$