# Evaluate the given limit to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

$ \lim_{n->\infty} {(1+2/n)^{n^2}  e^{-2n}}   $

Answer is not $\ e^0$ . OR atleast it was not in the options.

**My approach:**

$ \lim_{n->\infty} {(1+2/n)^{n^2} .e^{-2n}} $ = $ \lim_{n->\infty} {(1+2/n)^{n^2}}/{e^{2n}} $

=$ \lim_{n->\infty} {(1+2/n)^{n^2}}/{(e^2)^{n}} $

= $ \lim_{n->\infty} {(1+2/n)^{n^2}}/{{((1+2/n)^{n})}^n} $

=$ \lim_{n->\infty} {e^{2{n}}}/{{e}^{2n}} $

=$ e^0 $

But this was not in the options. But My method seems to be pretty correct as well.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The limit is eyesight doable and it's $1/e^2$.

Comment: @Von Neumann [eyesight?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646081/definite-integration-having-d-dx-operator-inside-the-integral-sign/2646083#2646083)

Comment: @ProfessorVector Yes. It's a problem if I can calculate fast?

Comment: @Von Neumann Except your first try was wrong, there.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I did not say I always get the right answer. Everyone get confused sometimes. In any case, HERE I am right ^_^ See the answer below!

Comment: @VonNeumann I have updated the question to include my method. Is there anything wrong in my approach?

Comment: @DomJo Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$ (1+2/n)^{n^2}=e^{n^2\log(1+2/n)}=e^{n^2(2/n-2/n^2+o(1/n^2))}=e^{2n-2+o(1)}$$

thus

$$ (1+2/n)^{n^2}  e^{-2n}=e^{-2+o(1)}\to \frac1{e^2}$$

Comment: Thanks. e^-2 was there in the option. But I'm not aware of the method that you used. Especially the 3rd step

Comment: What is wrong in my method

Comment: I take a look now.

Comment: The fact is that to take the limit you cannot substitute the expression $(1+2/n)^{n^2}$ with $e^{2n}$ or viceversa, sometimes this kind of trick can work but not in general and it is uncorrect. What is true is that  $(1+2/n)^{n^2} \sim e^{2n}$ in the sense that for n large they are of the same order of magnitude but $(1+2/n)^{n^2}$ is smaller with a factor of about $\frac{1}{e^{2}}$ wichvcan be found by Taylor’s expansion. If you are not aware with these methods I will look for some other alternative approach for you.

Comment: I know Taylor series expn. But I was unaware of O notation until you used it yesterday

Comment: @DomJo the little-o and big-O notations are used to handle remainder terms of the expansion, it is necessary that learn about it in order to use Taylor's expansion for limit calculation